# Setting up Python to run code at a certain time in local time

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a code and I want the code to run at 2 different times. For instance, when I  run the code I want it to run the first line:

```
print("Hello world")
```

then I want it to run the remaining of the code at a certain time (i.e. 11:23:31 EST):

```
print("Hello again")
```

What module can I use to do this in Python?

The actual code is a lot more complex than the just "Hello world". 
I'm new to coding.

Comment: no? I just asked to provide the module name that can do that. Never asked anyone to code for me. Please refrain from commenting if not willing to help.

Comment: You can write your program, and then use the at module to schedule it at a certain time if you're running linux. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/339298/conveniently-schedule-a-command-to-run-later

Comment: This python module also looks interesting: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule

Comment: @Arya Anyway I can do this through python as each consumer of the product wont be using linux? _nvm just saw your second comment!

Comment: If you have unix based system you could use `cron` utility and make it run Python script https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Comment: Why do you want to do this? With the limited information you've provided, it doesn't make a lot of sense. Why not just run the final program at 11:23:31 EST? Why print the first statement and wait?

Comment: question has already been solved. No need for further statements or unnecessary down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [schedule library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule)

```
import schedule
import time
import sys

def job1():
    print("hello world")

def job2():
    print("Hello again")
    sys.exit(0) # remove this if you want it to run every day at 11:23

schedule.every().day.at("11:23").do(job2)

job1()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```